# Prism MVVM: How can I open up multiple instances of a view in new windows?

Tags: windows, mvvm, view, prism, instances

My application displays a list of files. I have a view for displaying those files. I want to be able to select an item from list and have it open in a new window. But I also want to be able to select another item from the list so I can compare the two files.

I'm not quite sure where to start as I'm new to Prism. If someone can give me some direction on where to look or what to do, that would be great.

Comment: Please, provide some code so people can help you faster and understand better your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: To solve this, I created a shell service. There is a tutorial up for this on PluralSight. I can post code if someone needs it.